# 'CountryPDF' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Please help!What I am doing wrong?
I have views.py to generate PDF.
It is generate PDF success if context: 'Sometext'.It open me PDF link. But When I take django models.It output me : 'CountryPDF' object has no attribute 'data'

```
my views.py

class CountryPDF(core.PDFView):
    template_name = 'application_pdf.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return {'data': self.data}

    def get_file_name(self, context):
        return 'test1.pdf'
```

So HTML file:
application_pdf.html

```
{% for item in data %}
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.address }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
```

url:

```
path('cabinet/<int:pk>/download-pdf/',
         views.CountryPDF.as_view(),
         name='country-download_pdf'),
```

What is the problem with context data? What I am doing wrong?

```
class PDFView(TemplateView):
    changed_fonts = False

    def get_context(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_file_name(self, context):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data()
        ctx.update(self.get_context(**kwargs))
        return ctx
```

Comment: what is `core.PDFView`? Is that something you wrote?

Comment: yes.It is View which use for generate PDF print .Updated question